# Intersection and sum of spans not matching grassman

Tags: linear-algebra

I've stumbled upon this problem:
given A = span($\begin{pmatrix} 2 , 0 \\ 0 ,1\\ 1,0 \end{pmatrix} \;$)
and B = span($\begin{pmatrix} 1 , 0 \\ -1 ,0\\ 0,1 \end{pmatrix} \;$)

What's A+B? and what' A $\cap$ B?

As I remember, the span contains all linear combinations made with the given vectors, so I defined A as span($\begin{pmatrix} 2t  \\ s \\ t \end{pmatrix} \;$)
and B as ($\begin{pmatrix} t  \\ -t \\ s \end{pmatrix} \;$)

Now for the intersect I would take into a system both A and B like:

$\begin{cases}
      x=2t\\
      y=s\\
      z=t\\
x=t\\
y=-t\\
z=s
    \end{cases}$

Now I would replace the x,y,z with the other counterpart and end up like

$\begin{cases}
      t=2t\\
      -t=s\\
      s=t\\
    \end{cases}$

that solves with s = 0 and t = 0 , first is all of this right?

Second

since by the definition of span that i assume right( again correct me if I'm wrong )
there are 2 vector that behave independently so we have the form with t and s,
that , to me , looks like they both (A and B) have dimension 2
but for the Grassman theorem $\dim(A+B) = \dim(A)+\dim(B)-\dim(A \cap B)$
so $\dim(A+B) = 2+2-0$ and that doesn't sound right

Third, how would O find the cartesian representation of A+B? Following the definition
it's all the vectors that can be written as a sum of A and B, if they were 2 non parallel line A+B would be a plane, but this intuition doesn't suggest me anything now

Thank for the reading thus far.

(Edit)

The problem in my case was the misconception of cartesian and
parametric form ( mostly )

As for finding the sum A+B the steps are

- obtain a base of A and B
- create a generator by merging the bases
- extract the base of A+B from the generator ( check with Grassman the dimension of A+B)

Comment: You should be able to check relatively easily that the vector $(2,-2,1)$ belongs to the intersection. 
Maybe this might help you to spot the mistake or check your computations when you try this in the way suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I remember, the span contains all linear combinations made with the given vectors, so i defined A as span($\begin{pmatrix} 2t  \\ s \\ t \end{pmatrix} \;$)

You should have
$$ A = \{ (2t, s, t)' : s,t \in \mathbb R\}.$$
By putting span $(2t,s,t)'$ you have that $A$ is a one dimensional space which is not true.

> and B as ($\begin{pmatrix} t  \\ -t \\ s \end{pmatrix} \;$)

Written like this it looks like
$B$ only contains one vector. You should write instead
$$ B = \{ (t, -t, s)' : s,t \in \mathbb R\}$$

For the intersection you have $(x,y,z) \in A $ implies $\exists s,t$  such that
$(x,y,z) = (2t,s,t)$.
However $(x,y,z) \in B$ does not imply
$$ (x,y,z) = (t,-t,s)$$
for the same $t,s$ !!!

This is a common mistake. Instead you have $(x,y,z) \in B$ implies that $\exists s_1,t_1$ such that
$$(x,y,z) = (t_1,-t_1,s_1) $$
the mistake you're making is that you are incorrectly assuming that $s_1,t_1$ are the same as $s,t$ found when stating $(x,y,z) \in A$.

You should start over.

---

Alternatively you could notice that the set $A$ is exactly the set of points which verify $$ 2z = x$$
and $B$ is the set of points which verify $$ y = -x$$ so the intersection must verify both equations.